# angular. $location.search doesn't update browser address bar

Tags: angularjs

maybe one of you have an idea what's going wrong in our angularjs application (unfortunately I cann't share the code).

What we do:

- we call $location.search(params1)
  => Nothing happens in the browser address bar
- in the next step we call $location.search(params2)
  => Now we see the browser address bar is changed, but params1 are there instead of params2
  ... and so on.

Does anybody hava a clue for us?

Comment: Try to call a $scope.$digest or $scope.$apply ($rootScope will do as well).

Comment: Can you post your exact code? I do this all the time and haven't experienced this. Also what version of Angular & UI Router are you using?

Comment: you may need to specify the query parameters in your state declaration. something like `url: "/contacts?myParam&myParam2&myParam3"`. Take a look here: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#user-content-query-parameters

Comment: @Fidel90 nope, that doesn't help

Comment: @MikeFeltman I believe you, the same to us. We didn't have any problems using $location.search. But for this one case it just works very strange as if there is a one step delay

Comment: @Fidel90 ok $scope.$apply did the work, but actually I don't really understand, why it works in any other cases without

Comment: Well, that's impossible to tell when noone knows your code ;-) Anyway I'm glad that at least it works.

Answer (score 0):

How are you triggering the $location.search() function?

It sounds like you might need to call $scope.$digest() after firing $location.search() but I can't say for sure with your example.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this working example of how $location.search works:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function MyCtrl($scope, $location) {

    $scope.location = $location;
    $scope.$watch('location.search()', function() {
        $scope.target = ($location.search()).target;
    }, true);

    $scope.changeTarget = function(name) {
        $location.search('target', name);
    }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pvffcfq6/

It's possible you need to run a $scope.digest somewhere in your code?

Comment: The question wasn't how to use $location.search, but about strange behaviour

Comment: It could be useful for newbies. I also mentioned that $scope.digest might be necessary.